# How to use pytest fixture in class constructor

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I'm using pytest and trying to create object that supposed to be used in many classes of my project.
I am trying to pass the object to one of the classes but the pycharm show me 'Unresolved reference 'custom_inst'.

Here is my code:

conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def fixture_example(request):
    custom_inst = FixtureClass()
    yield custom_inst
    custom_inst.do_something()
```

some class:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('fixture_example')
class DummyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1=None, arg2=None):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.custom_inst = fixture_example
```

how can I pass the instance 'custom_inst' to my DummyClass as class member?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you try to mix pytest entity(fixture) and non-pytest entity(class DummyClass).

In this case DummyClass will never execute by pytest, because pytest runner collects and executes classes that [start from "Test" keyword only](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-discovery).
In other hand if you call DummyClass() directly, fixture_example will not execute because only pytest runner use it.